# How do I print the output of my SQL query using python?

Tags: python, stored-procedures

Here is my code:

```
def exceptions_function(self):
    exceptions_function_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY = "CALL sp_exceptions_function_Exceptions();"
    vfcaa = self.config["verafin-exceptions"]["functions"]["exceptions_function"]
    if vfcaa:
        with self.DB_connection() as cnxn:
            with cnxn.cursor() as cur:
                try:
                    cur.execute(exceptions_function_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY)
                    print("exceptions_function exceptions query ran successfully, {} exceptions updated.".format(cur.rowcount))

                except pm.Error as e:
                    print(f"Error: {e}")

                except Exception as e:
                    logging.exception(e)

                else:
                    cnxn.commit()
```

Right now I am just printing off the number of exceptions records created. I am trying to print off each individual record. I tried creating a dataframe using:

```
data=DataFrame(cur.fetchall())
for row in data:
    print(row)
```

But it was empty. I don't think I am executing my stored procedure correctly? It finds the difference between the current day's and previous day's records and outputs them to a table. But in my python script when I am calling it, I am only getting the number of exceptions records created. How do I print each record in its entirety?

UPDATE:

```
def run_all(self):
    def function_name(self):
        function_name_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY = "CALL sp_function_name_Exceptions();"
        vfcaa = self.config["verafin-exceptions"]["functions"]["function_name"]
        cnxn=self.DB_connection()
        cur=cnxn.cursor()            
        if vfcaa:
            try:
                cur.execute(function_name_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY)
                print("function_name exceptions query ran successfully, {} exceptions updated.".format(cur.rowcount))
                data=cur.fetchall()
                print(data)
            except pm.Error as e:
                print(f"Error: {e}")

            except Exception as e:
                logging.exception(e)

            else:
                cnxn.commit()
    function_name(self)
```

STORED PROCEDURE:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (
`updated`,
`inst_num`,
`brnc_num`,
`cust_num`,
`snp_date`
) 
SELECT 
table1.`updated`,
table1.`inst_num`,
table1.`brnc_num`,
table1.`cust_num`
table1.`snp_date`
FROM table_snapshot table1
LEFT JOIN table_snapshot table2 
    ON table1.`cust_num` = table2.`cust_num`
    AND table2.`snp_date` = CURDATE()
WHERE table1.`snp_date` = CURDATE()- INTERVAL 1 DAY
AND table2.`cust_num` IS NULL;
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with the way you're calling the procedure. Are you sure it's returning something?

Comment: You can just do `data = cur.fetchall()` then `print(data)`

Comment: I updated my comment with how I incorporated the code and my stored procedure. The way I wrote the python doesn't return anything. My stored procedure returns the number of records that were created when I run it, it doesn't output a table directly from executing it.

Comment: `INSERT` queries don't return any results, there's nothing to print.

Comment: You need to add `SELECT ROW_COUNT();` to the stored procedure to get the number of rows that were added.

Comment: Can a call be fetched? Wouldn't you have to select from a function?

Comment: I  added SELECT ROW_COUNT(); to the stored procedure and re-ran my python script. Now this is the output: ((3206,),). Just the row count, not each record.

Comment: Nevermind, I did: SELECT * FROM table WHERE date=CURDATE(); and it outputted the records in pandas. I just need to make it pretty

Answer (score 0):

Look in to [pandas.read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html)

It's a convenient way to send sql queries to a database and get the reuslt back as a DataFrame.

Your code would become soemthing along the lines of:

```
def exceptions_function(self):
    exceptions_function_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY = "CALL sp_exceptions_function_Exceptions();"
    vfcaa = self.config["verafin-exceptions"]["functions"]["exceptions_function"]
    if vfcaa:
        with self.DB_connection() as cnxn:
            with cnxn.cursor() as cur:
                try:
                    result = pd.read_sql(exceptions_function_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY, cnxn)
                    print("exceptions_function exceptions query ran successfully, {} exceptions updated.".format(result .shape[0]))

                except pm.Error as e:
                    print(f"Error: {e}")
                except Exception as e:
                    logging.exception(e)
     else:
       cnxn.commit()
```